# How to select lines between two similar patterns

Tags: awk

I have a text file that contains text blocks like this:

```
IN
hit
ER 123 hit 456
abc
hit
ghi
ER 789 hit 012
abc
ghi
IN 345 
abc
def
ghi
ER 678 xxx 901
xyz
hit
xyz
IN
risk
in
```

Blocks can have any number of lines, but always start with line containing ER or IN.

Using awk how can I select lines which are occurring between two similar marker patterns?

1) There may be multiple sections marked with these patterns.

2) One of selected lines between patterns must contain another pattern (eg. hit)

3) Line with first pattern (eg. ER) should be included, line with second one (eg. ER|IN) should be excluded.

Expected output:

```
ER 123 hit 456
abc
hit
ghi
ER 678 xxx 901
xyz
hit
xyz
```

I've tried to achieve my goal with

```
awk '/ER/ {block=1} block {str=str sep $0; sep=RS} /ER|IN/ {block=0; if (str~/hit/) {print str} str=sep=""}'
```

but it gives me

```
ER abc hit ghi
ER 789 hit 012
```

EDIT: my example wasn't precise enough.
EDIT2:

a) I try to find line matching pattern " ER "
b) I search for nearest next line matching pattern " ER " or " IN "
c) I want to print result only if my result contains at least one line matching pattern ".*hit.*", but it can't be first line. Result should include first line, but exclude last line, so:

```
ER 678 xxx 901
xyz
hit
xyz
```

should be printed, because there is one line matching hit in block between line matching " ER " and line matching " IN "

```
ER 789 hit 012
abc
ghi
```

shouldn't be printed, because there is no line matching hit in block between line matching " ER " and line matching " IN "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
/ER/ && val{
  if(hit_flag){
    print val};
  val=hit_flag=token=in_er_token=""
}
/ER/ && !val{
  val=$0;
  token=1
  next
}
val && token && (/[Hh][Ii][Tt]/){
  hit_flag=1
}
val && token && (/ER/ || /[Ii][Nn]/){
  if(val){
    in_er_token=1
    };
  next}
!in_er_token{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
END{
  if(val && hit_flag){
    print val}
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough, I've changed my example. Lines may start with other character, they have to contain ER, so I need to remove "^", but hit should be between first and last line (excluding them).

Comment: @Bartosz, I believe that is what needed right not to have `IN` in it? Please do let me know on same and in comments add by adding coding in backticks.

Comment: almost. For block: 
`ER 678 xxx 901 
xyz 
hit 
xyz 
IN 
risk 
IN` it gives: 
`ER 678 xxx 901 
xyz 
hit 
xyz 
risk`

Comment: Not exactly - lines with `IN` were skipped and line with `risk` was printed.It wasn't between `ER` and `ER|IN` lines. Updated example.

Comment: @Bartosz, could you please run my code once, I haven't seen `ER 789 hit 012` in my output, please do let me know on same.

Comment: I had to update my example, so please check if you have newest one. I updated it because it looks like your code will print also all lines before first `ER` line.

Comment: line `risk` still being printed.

Comment: @Bartosz, ok let's give 1 more try, I have edited my code, check and let me know then?

Comment: @Bartosz, please do let us know if this helped you?

Comment: yes, it works great for example, but I've checked that in my real file there are still some blocks that won't be processed correctly.
Anyway, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk with `RT`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="(ER|IN)"}NR==1{rt=RT}{ORS=RT}/\nhit/{print (NR==2?rt:"")$0}' file
ER 123 hit 456
abc
hit
ghi
ER 678 xxx 901
xyz
hit
xyz
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS="(ER|IN)" }      # record separator is ER or IN
NR==1 { rt=RT }             # special handling it hit is in the second record
{ ORS=RT }                  # set matched RS as ORS
/\nhit/ {                   # hit in the record
    print (NR==2?rt:"") $0  # output with special handling for NR==2
}' file
```

The definition for `ER` and `IN` and `hit` could be tighter. Mind that when you implement it for your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^(ER|IN)\>/{
         if (f) { if (r ~ /\<hit\>/) print head, r }
         f=1; head=$0; r=""; next
     }
     f{ r=r ORS $0 }' file
```

The output:

```
ER 123 hit 456 
abc
hit
ghi
ER 678 hit 901 
xyz
hit
xyz
```